# Does the aspect ratio of an electromagnetic coil affect the efficiency of magnetic coupling to a magnetic core?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, magnets

Let's imagine we have multiple different sizes of magnetic coils, however they all have the same number of turns and use the same gauge of wire. They all share the same geometry for their magnetic core.

In practice, if you had a long, skinny coil, would more of the magnetic flux be coupled to the magnetic core than a short fat one?

How does the distance between the wire and the magnetic core affect the efficiency of the magnetic coupling?

Would the most efficient coil be distributed all around the magnetic core like in a toroidal transformer rather than in discrete bobbins such as in an E-core transformer?

Comment: Pretty sure it does. Longer motors are more efficient than shorter ones for similar reasons. It has to do with the relative coupling area versus the area at the ends where you have stray flux.

Comment: Could you please provide some example this was shown to be true? Longer magnetic cores will also have a greater magnetic reluctance for a given cross-sectional area.

Comment: I was just that told that by my professor that's what companies do for the "same" model of motor in Europe vs North America (the required efficiencies are different by regulations) and it seems to match if you get a chance to look at motor power ratings from companies where they just make the longer motor. The longer motor handles disproportionately more power and the higher aspect ratio motors seem to handle more power than the lower aspect ratio motors of the same class. Like on Neumotor.